# django view method signature is it possible to match GET parameters?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Is it possible to make matches between:

urls regex def in **`urls.py:`**

```
...
     url(r'^edit_notification/(?P<foo>\d+)/$', 'edit_notification')
...
```

and method signature in **`views.py:`**

```
def edit_notification(request, foo):
  ...
```

for GET parameters in Django?

Or the only way is external inside method `request.GET.get('foo')`

Comment: It does not makes sense. If you want them defined in the url configuration then why not use it as `{% url 'url_name' foo_param %}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET` parameters [are not matched by the url configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against):

> What the URLconf searches against The URLconf searches against the
>   requested URL, as a normal Python string. This does not include GET or
>   POST parameters, or the domain name.

They are a part of `HttpRequest` object and are kept inside [`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) `QueryDict`

```
def edit_notification(request):
    foo = request.GET.get('foo')
    ...
```